# Class method for open new forms C#

Tags: c#, .net

I wondering if there's another way to do this code below in a method, because I'm calling this method with different form instances in almost all of my forms.
**So what I need is create a code like:**

```
public void NewForm(Form target)
...
target myform = new target();
target.Show();
...
```

And call it like:

```
NewForm(Form2);
```

Comment: Are you asking how to instantiate a form by name?

Comment: Have a look here: https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2019/02/11/instantiating-a-c-object-from-a-string-using-activator-createinstance-in-net/

Comment: Sure. Make public [generic method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods)

Comment: I have a hard time finding out what the variables in your code are since you posted only a single implementation... can you explain *in plain english* what varies between different implementations of your methods?

Comment: Only put the line : "target myform = new target();: in main form.  Then pass myform to all other forms.

Comment: `public void NewForm<T>() where T:Form, new() { T frm = new T(); ... }`

Comment: I agree that Generics sounds like the Droid you should be looking for. They are there to deal with "insert type at compile time" scenarios. If generics can not solve it, we propably need a whole lot more information. This might even be a XY problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @nvoigt I just need a class that open diferent forms, for example: 
NewForm(layout); //Opens layout form,
NewForm(Form2); //Opens Form2

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, call the method passing the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how useful such a method is but, there are several approaches you could take.

### A generic method

Definition:

```
void NewForm<T>()
  where T : Form, new()
{
  T instance = new T();
  instance.show();
}
```

Invocation:

```
NewForm<LayoutForm>();
```

- Pros:

  - Type-checked at compile-time
  - Safe
- Cons:

  - Not the format you asked for.
  - Does not allow for Parameters to be passed.

### A Type argument function

Definition:

```
void NewForm(Type formType)
{
    if(formType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Form)))
    {
        var form = Activator.CreateInstance(formType) as Form;
        form.show();
    }
}
```

Invocation:

```
NewForm(LayoutForm);
```

- Pros:

  - You asked for this format
- Cons:

  - Does not allow for Parameters to be passed to the constructor.
  - Does throw if the type is not creatable with `Activator.CreateInstance(x);`
  - Runtime type-checking

### Passing a Form Instance

Definition:

```
void NewForm(Form form)
{
  form.show();
}
```

Invocation:

```
NewForm(new LayoutForm());
```

- Pros:

  - Allows for parameters to be passed.
  - Safe -> Type checked at compile-time.
- Cons:

  - Not the format you asked for
  - Kinda pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) for the code and the other guys who showed me generic methods. I didn't know about this generic methods.

Class.cs

```
public void NewForm<T>() where T:Form, new() 
{ 
T frm = new T(); ... 
frm.Show();
}
```

Form.cs

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
NewForm<Form2>();
}
```